# Use 2 different page number formats in same document - MS Word 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have first 10 pages numbered by `Roman` digits.

I want that the 11th page's numbering should start by 1, 2, 3 and so on...

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **Section Break**

Source [Insert a section break](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx)

> You can use section breaks to change the layout or formatting of a page or pages in your document. For example, you can lay out part of a single-column page as two columns. **You can separate the chapters in your document so that the page numbering for each chapter begins at 1**. You can also create a different header or footer for a section of your document.
>
> **Insert a section break**
>
> - On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Breaks.
>
> [image]
>
> - Click the type of section break that you want to use.

Comment: I have learnt a new thing today PAGE BREAKS. I wasnt aware of that